# How can a Web API Client read a complex type from response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created a POST Action which should return a Complex type as shown below as part of the HTTPContent:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("users/verifyLoginCredentials")]
    public IHttpActionResult VerifyLoginCredentials([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> loginCredentials) // Purely here for testing purouses
    {
        Models.User user = new Models.User();
        string username = (loginCredentials.ContainsKey("userLogin"))? loginCredentials["userLogin"]: "";
        string password = (loginCredentials.ContainsKey("password"))? loginCredentials["password"] : "";

        var verificationResult = Models.User.VerifyLoginCredentials(username, password, out user);
        HttpContent responseContent = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));

        if (verificationResult)
        {   
            return Ok(responseContent);
        }

        return BadRequest("Login Failed");
    }
```

And then within my client application I want to read the Complex type which has been serialised to a Json object so the obvious would be to de-serialise it, but where is it(the User Object)?

```
    public static async Task<bool> VerifyCredentials(string userLogin, string password)
    {
        var value = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "userLogin", userLogin },
           { "password", password }
        };

        var test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        var content = new StringContent(test, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = await WebApiHelper.Client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials", content);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var user = (User)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultContent);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: "so the obvious would be to de-serialise it, but where is it?" - Where is what? What is the problem you're having?

Comment: @john, A User object should be present in the response from the POST Action, how can I read that object from the response?

Comment: Use the same constructor of `StringContent` in you controller as you use in `VerifyCredentials` , the one that takes the encoding and content type.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I have typed up an answer for you as I know what the problem is, but I won't post it until you update your question with all of the information you have (including any exceptions).

Comment: @Crowcoder, I don't get what you mean, I am already using that constructor to include the User Object in the response. My question is about reading it from the response not adding it to the response!

Comment: Why don't you just `return Ok(user);` ?

Comment: @john No Exceptions are thrown, there is a Json object/string that represents the User object somewhere in the HTTP response and I don't know where!

Comment: @Crowcoder Because I thought that Ok() only takes a HTTPContent type, now that you pointed it I realised what I was doing! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### On the client side

Instead of doing this in two steps:

```
var result = await WebApiHelper.Client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials", content);
/*1: read as string*/string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

/*2: deserialize*/ var user = (User)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultContent);
```

You can do this in one step:

```
var result = await WebApiHelper.Client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials", content);
/*1: read as User*/User resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>();
```

This, however:

```
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return true;
}
```

Has to be checked *before* attempting to deserialize, otherwise you would be trying to deserialize "Login Failed" as a User object - which of course isn't valid. So:

```
public static async Task<bool> VerifyCredentials(string userLogin, string password)
{
    var value = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "userLogin", userLogin },
       { "password", password }
    };

    var test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    var content = new StringContent(test, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var result = await WebApiHelper.Client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials", content);

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return true;
    }

    User resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>();

    return false;
}
```

I am not sure whether you win anything by that deserialization though

---

#### On the server side

This code here:

```
var verificationResult = Models.User.VerifyLoginCredentials(username, password, out user);
HttpContent responseContent = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));

if (verificationResult)
{   
    return Ok(responseContent);
}
```

Is overly complex. Web API already JSON-serializes the model by default, you don't have to do all of that. Instead:

```
var verificationResult = Models.User.VerifyLoginCredentials(username, password, out user);

if (verificationResult)
{   
    return Ok(user);
}
```

Also, you should be using a proper Data Transfer Object (DTO), instead of receiving a Dictionary that you cannot have the Framework validate for you, but that's another problem.

Comment: Thanks, For some reason I thought that Ok() only takes in a HttpContent Type obviously I was wrong, I know some of the code in there does not make sense and can be taken out, I will take it out as the method evolves

Comment: @Aboudi It always helps to look at IntelliSense and see all of the available options. You are welcome

Comment: I did, but for some I take a quick glance and read only some letters, then assume what was actually written, very bad habit that costs me!

Comment: I guess DTO is where I Declare a complex type and decorate it's properties with validation attributes which will allow me to use something like Model.IsValid?

Comment: @Aboudi Yes, exactly. That's using best practices in a ASP.NET MVC/Web API application